# How to implement web to case with record types and dependent picklists?

Tags: web-to-case

I have 2 different record types.

Each record type has 2 picklists and one is dependent.
For example:
1st picklist is Type - values: A, B, C, D
2nd picklist is Sub-Type: E, F, G, H, I, J

If I select record type 1 then I can select values A or B.
If I select A then I can only selct E or F for subtype.

Comment: On top of my head you might not be able to use dependent picklist natively as web2lead form is plain without javascript. Probably need some js developer to make it dependednt?

Comment: Web-to-case means you have to write your own code. You can build the dependencies via jQuery or another solution.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses